# How to make a block of code execute without interruption Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, web-crawler, atomic

I'm trying to create a web crawler.
I've created a class to handle all URLs visited and to visit.
This class has to be accessed by multiple threads for retrieving and updating those lists.
The problem I'm facing, or at least I think, is in **nextRandom()** and probably also in **next()**. I think what is happening is the threads are interfering with each other since the function is somewhat synchronized but not atomic. Is there a way to make so this block of code is executed without any interruption by other threads?

### The URL handler

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class UrlHandler {
    private volatile Set<String> visited = new HashSet<String>();
    private volatile List<String> toVisit = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void addToVisit(String url) {
        synchronized (this){
            if (!visited.contains(url)) toVisit.add(url);
        }
    }

    public void addToVisit(Collection<String> urls) {
        synchronized (this){
            for (String url : urls)
                if (!visited.contains(url)) toVisit.add(url);
        }
    }

    public void addVisited(String url){
        synchronized (this){
            visited.add(url);
        }
    }
    public void addVisited(Collection<String> urls){
        synchronized (this){
            visited.addAll(urls);
        }
    }

    public String next() {

        while (toVisit.size() == 0) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(200);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        synchronized (this){
            String url = toVisit.get(0);
            toVisit.remove(0);
            return url;

        }
    }

    public String nextRandom() {
        synchronized (this){
            int n = 0;
            if (toVisit.size() > 1){
                n = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(toVisit.size());
            }

            String url = toVisit.get(n);
            toVisit.remove(n);
            return url;
        }
    }

    public List<String> getToVisit() {
        synchronized (this){
            return toVisit;
        }
    }

    public Set<String> getVisited() {
        synchronized (this){
            return visited;
        }
    }
}
```

### Web Crawler

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class WebCrawler {
    private final ExecutorService executor;

    public WebCrawler(int nOfThreads) {
        this.executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nOfThreads);
    }

    public void add(Runnable runnable) {
        this.executor.execute(runnable);
    }

    //Used to shut down safely and wait also 5 of seconds for not finished tasks
    public void shutdown() {
        this.executor.shutdown();
        try {
            this.executor.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            if (!this.executor.isTerminated()) {
                System.err.println("Timed out waiting for executor to terminate cleanly. Shutting down.");
                this.executor.shutdownNow();
            }
        } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
            System.err.println("Interrupted while waiting for executor shutdown.");
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
}
```

### Failing test example

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

public class UrlHandlerTest {

    List<String> testList = new ArrayList<>(List.of("test1", "test2", "test3", "test3"));
    List<String> uniqueTestList = new ArrayList<>(List.of("test1", "test2", "test3"));
    UrlHandler urlHandler = new UrlHandler();

    @Test
    public void concurrentAccess(){
        urlHandler.addToVisit(testList);

        WebCrawler webCrawler = new WebCrawler(10);
        for (int i = 0; i < urlHandler.getToVisit().size(); i++) {
            webCrawler.add(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    String url = urlHandler.nextRandom();
                    urlHandler.addVisited(url);
                    System.out.println("Here thread " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " working on: " + url);
                }
            });
        }

        webCrawler.shutdown();

        System.out.println(urlHandler.getVisited());
        assertEquals(true, urlHandler.getVisited().containsAll(uniqueTestList));
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be creating a new Random object ever time you want  a new random number.  Try using a ThreadLocal to hold the a Random instance for each thread.  https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I have updated the code with your suggestions. Still the problem persist.

Answer (score 2):

In the next method this code is a problem:

```
    while (toVisit.size() == 0) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(200);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The lock isn't held for this part, so size can be stale. Instead of this, try something like

```
while (toVisit.size() == 0) 
    wait();
```

Do this in a synchronized block so  you have the lock held while checking the collection size. Code that adds to the collection should notify in order to wake up the waiting threads.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was for sure a problem. I solved by synchronizing on **this** for all the methods. However the main problem remains...

Comment: @Andrea: maybe things using this are updating the collections directly? Passing out references to the members would allow that to happen. Safer to make defensive copies.

Comment: Yes good point I will do it eventually. But that is not the problem in this case since I am not using those methods anywhere.

Comment: @Andrea: then update the question with current code and provide a [mcve] to have the best chance of getting good answers.

Comment: Done. Thank you for the suggestion. Was trying to keep the question as simple as possible

Comment: Thank you this is a nice suggestion to make the code cleaner

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code is problematic:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < urlHandler.getToVisit().size(); i++) {
            webCrawler.add(new Runnable() {
                // ...
            });
        }
```

The `urlHandler.getToVisit().size()` is always changing during the traversal, and there is uncertainty (because the size will be changed asynchronously).

Change to:

```
        int size = urlHandler.getToVisit().size();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            webCrawler.add(new Runnable() {
                // ...
            });
        }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that was the problem. For some reason I thought the two code were doing the same thing but apparently the size is checked at each iteration and not saved when the for is firstly met.

Comment: Yes. ```for (statement 1; statement 2; statement 3)```:  only ```Statement 1``` is executed (one time) before the execution of the code block.